# how to skip NOOBS boot menu

Tags: boot, keyboard, noobs

So I installed Raspbian and OSMC on my pi and I like using both, but is there a way to skip the 8 second boot menu? 
I `ssh` into raspbian often which can require rebooting, so it adds an extra 8 seconds to the wait time when I reboot.

Is there a way to choose which starts the boot and then maybe open the other OS's from the first?

Or more likely, a way to open the boot menu only if a keyboard key is held down during startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the SD card in another machine: You should see the RECOVERY partition. Create the text file: `autoboot.txt` at the root level of this partition.

Note: Be careful in Windows that if you create a textfile, you can just call it `autoboot` because it will already be a `.txt` file. I accidently tried to use `autoboot.txt.txt` and it took me a minute to realize the issue.

Put a single line in the text file:

```
boot_partition=6
```

Note, from my source, you may instead need to use the line

```
boot_partition=5
```

https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/Skip-noobs-screen-(EN)

Thanks to rockaddicted@github

Note, finally, that this also removes the Rainbow image that NOOBS puts as the very initial spash screen.

Comment: So 5 or 6 are the numbers of the the first 2 installed OSs?

Comment: Yeah, how does one discover the partition numbers?

Comment: See these [Noobs](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained) [explanations](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/Standalone-partitioning-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for doing it on a pi:

- run `lxterminal`
- run `sudo fdisk -l`
- determine the partition that contains the boot loader for the OS:

  - probably you'll have multiple W95 FAT Type ones; the NOOBS recovery partition is quite big (couple of Gb), and it is this partition you will write an `autoboot.txt` file to.
  - inside the `autoboot.txt` file you will cite which partition to boot - the partition you want to boot from is a smaller W95 FAT one
- look at the (numbers in the) first column, for example:

  - `mmcblk0p1 1.8G W95FAT` - this is partition 1, the NOOBS partition you need to mount
  - `mmcblk0p6 69M W95FAT` - this is partition 6 which might, for example, be the partition you want to boot directly
- mount the NOOBS partition: `mkdir /media/noobs` followed by `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/noobs`
- cd to the mounted noobs parition: `cd /media/noobs`
- create a text file called `autoboot.txt`: `sudo nano autoboot.txt`
- inside nano, write: `boot_partition=6`

  - the 6 comes from `mmcblk0p6` from the `fsdisk` output, 6 being the smaller W95 partition. Your number may vary
- write the file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
- exit the partition: `cd ..`
- unmount the partition: `sudo umount /media/noobs`